# Oracle SQL : summarize genealogy data into sequential order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a parent-child relationship table as below

```
src_data      date       dst_data         key
---------------------------------------------
P1         2018-01-01       D2            123
D2         2018-01-02       D3            123
D3         2018-01-03       D4            123
```

I wanted to create a query/SQL to display as below

```
key        link
-----------------
123        P1
123        D2
123        D3
123        D4
```

How can I do it? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the query to list, for a given key, the parent and all the children and granchildren etc in order?

Answer (score 1):

Although, your question is not pretty much clear but below is the query for the required output

```
SELECT srcData as Link, KEY
FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT dst_data As Link, Key
FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a hierarchical query, the rows are already ordered as you want it:

```
SELECT key, src_data, dst_data
  FROM t
 WHERE key = 123
 START WITH src_data = 'P1'
 CONNECT BY src_data =  PRIOR dst_data;

123 P1  D2
123 D2  D3
123 D3  D4
```

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use self full outer join and add some type of order sequence or primary key. And please try to prepare test data next time to save us time typing:

```
WITH test_data AS
(
SELECT 1 row_seq, 'P1' src_data,  '2018-01-01' src_date,  'D2' dst_data, 123 data_key FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'D2', '2018-01-02', 'D3', 123  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'D3', '2018-01-03', 'D4', 123  FROM dual
)
SELECT NVL(a.src_data, b.dst_data) all_data
FROM test_data a FULL OUTER JOIN test_data b ON a.src_data = b.dst_data
ORDER BY a.row_seq
/
```

Output - you can add the rest of columns:

```
ALL_DATA
---------
P1
D2
D3
D4
```